# change UID of app in debug mode in Android studio

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, uid

i want testing  share data between two apps that have same UID. how change UID of apps in android studio and set a  same UID for two diffrent apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `sharedUserId` which will share data between two different apps.

In manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="string"
          android:sharedUserId="your_uid_in_string" // change here..
          android:sharedUserLabel="string resource" 
          android:versionCode="integer"
```

[Manifest Elements for Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html)